# How to store a specific list value

Tags: jquery, html

I have generated some list that looks like this:

```
<div id="floating-panel">
  <ul class="rss">
    <li id="list_0"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="displayPopUp();">Diana</a></li>
    <li id="list_1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="displayPopUp();">Paul</a></li>
    <li id="list_2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="displayPopUp();">Robert</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It could be a larger or smaller list, the ID's are always unique as displayed in the example... My question is how do I know which list item I clicked on so I could save the data, in this case the name 'Diana' or 'Paul'?  I need the information between the tags stored somewhere in PHP so I know which person was clicked on.

To give some more context, when the reference is clicked, a same page pop up window opens with a place to give user info, I also need the name of the link that was clicked on.

Comment: why not put the value in the js function `displayPopUp('Diana')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element which triggered the event:

```
function displayPopUp(event) {
    var name = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

More info on event.target: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

I'm not a pro with JavaScript, this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: No problem Brayden, glad tot help.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get link otherwise title you can simply do it with jQuery:

1. Add event listener to `li` elements.
2. Proceed data from event initiator: get link title and href.

```js
$('.rss').find('li').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).find('a');
    alert(link.html());
    alert(link.attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <ul class="rss">
    <li id="list_0"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Diana</a></li>
    <li id="list_1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Paul</a></li>
    <li id="list_2"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Robert</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the text from the a within the li on the click, but a better approach is to use HTML5's data attribute to get the name of the person on a given clicked li.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.rss li').click(function(){
  var name = $(this).data('name');
   displayPopUp(name);
   })
   
   
 function displayPopUp(name) {
   console.log(name);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <ul class="rss">
    <li id="list_0" data-name="Diana"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Diana</a></li>
    <li id="list_1" data-name="Paul"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Paul</a></li>
    <li id="list_2" data-name="Robert"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Robert</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```